# Remove Div Attribute when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I'm very new to JavaScript, not really sure what I'm doing. I found some useful code that removes/inserts a Div's attributes when a certain value is selected from a dropdown list. I'd like to modify this code so that the attribute is altered when a radio button is selected.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
        var rangeType = $('#<%= DateRangeList.ClientID%>').val();
        if (rangeType == 6) {
            $('#DatePeriodRow').removeAttr("style");
        }
        else {
            $('#DatePeriodRow').attr("style", "display: none;");
        }
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%= DateRangeList.ClientID %>').live("change", function() {
        var rangeType = $('#<%= DateRangeList.ClientID %>').val();
        if (rangeType == 6) {
            $('#DatePeriodRow').removeAttr("style");
        }
        else {
            $('#DatePeriodRow').attr("style", "display: none;");
        }
    });
})
```

I've been trying various ways of rebuilding this code to suit my needs but no luck thus far. I've also done quite a bit of Googling to no avail. I often receive the "Propery/Value is null or undefined" message, and I'm not to sure how to go about debugging the java side of things.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to show hide and element, Raki's answer will do. You could also express it this way:

```
$('#DatePeriodRow').hide(); // Hide Div
$('#DatePeriodRow').show(); // Show Div
```

First things first though, if your Property/Value is undefined or null you probably have a problem with your selectors. I.e. the following line:

```
$('#<%= DateRangeList.ClientID %>')
```

The <%= ... %> looks like ASP, if this is intended to be run inside that environment perhaps that code is not evaluating correctly which is giving you the wrong jQuery selector.

#### One More Thing

Check which version of jQuery you're using, `.live()` is deprecated, newer versions use `.on`

Comment: You're 100% right Matt, I know my problem lies with my selector. I've made a lot of changes but I'm still unable to ascertain why my script can't seem to see the radio button object. <asp:RadioButton GroupName="Rads" ID="radCustom" Value="Show" Text="Period" TextAlign="Left" runat="server"></asp:RadioButton>

Comment: What does the HTML output look like? I'm very rusty with my .NET skills (PHP dev) but I can probably help you from the HTML angle.

Comment: Sorry Matt, what do you mean by HTML output? What do you need?

Comment: When you view this page in the browser and inspect the source, what does the HTML for that radio button look like?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. My mind has been somewhat blown the the Markup language created at runtime. I noted the 'name' attribute within the input tag is 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Rads'. Here it is - <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_radCustom">Period</label><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_radCustom" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Rads" value="Show" />

Comment: Changing my js selector id to the id found in the input id att did the trick. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was getting at. Anytime!

Answer (score 1):

instead of using  `$('#DatePeriodRow').removeAttr("style");`  use 
`$('#DatePeriodRow').css("display", "none");` in order to hide div and 
`$('#DatePeriodRow').css("display", "block");` to display div

Comment: Thanks for advice.

Comment: check this example if you confused with above answer http://jsfiddle.net/Rakesh_V_R/MsYqx/3862/

Comment: Does it matter where I place the script on an ASP.net document? I had a look at your fiddle and tried to replicate, but no luck thus far.

Comment: no because this code will be written inside <script> </script> tag

Comment: can i know what is $("#DatePeriodRow") whether html element or aspx element

Comment: It's a html element.

Comment: Hi @Raki, see the comments under the post marked as answer. That was what resolved the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ASP Radio-button list is rendered as a table which contains html inputs with type "radio". So you need to add "input" to selector. The code below assigns handler to each radio-button when document is loaded and also checks if one of the buttons has been checked already. If it was - it fires "change" event to trigger the handler. Hope it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#<%=DateRangeList.ClientID%> input').bind("change",
            function ()
            {
                if ($(this).val() == "6") {
                    $("#DatePeriodRow").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#DatePeriodRow").hide();
                }
            });

        var checkedButton = $('#<%=DateRangeList.ClientID%> input[checked]').first();
        if (checkedButton.val())
        {
            checkedButton.trigger("change");
        }
    });
```